# W/System.err: java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

Tags: android

I want to send data by using LTE but while receive the data, connected server is stop and I have lost some data.

How to fix this error?

and how can I wrote the code for open server to receive data around 30 min and server socket will not closed before recieve all data?

source code for connect to server:

```js
     @Override
    public void run(){
        while (flg_loop) {
            try {
                clientSocket = echoSocket.accept();
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(4800000);
                clientth = new EchoThread(clientSocket);
                clientth.start();
            }catch (SocketTimeoutException s){
                startServer(serverip,serverportnum);
            }catch (IOException e) {
                startServer(serverip,serverportnum);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private class EchoThread extends Thread {
        protected Socket socket;
        protected boolean flg_open;
        String str;
        String str1;
        String str2;
        int s;
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                DataInputStream in = null;
                DataOutputStream out = null;
                if(socket.isConnected() == true) {
                    in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                }
                int len = 0;
                byte rxbuf[] = new byte[16000];
                flg_loop = true;
                while(flg_loop) {
                    len = in.read(rxbuf);
                    if(req_disconnect != 0){
                        req_disconnect = 0;
                        //clientth.stop();
                        clientSocket.close();
                        str = "ソケットクローズ" ;
                        MainActivity.printString(str);
                    }
                     if(this.socket.isConnected() == false){
                         try {
                             this.socket = echoSocket.accept();
                             flg_accept = true;
                         }catch(IOException e){
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                        this.socket.setSoTimeout(4800000);
                         if(flg_accept != false) {
                             //flg_accept = false;
                             str = "接続" ;
                             //startServer(serverip, serverportnum);
                         }else
                         {
                             str = "接続切れました" ;
                         }
                         //mActivity.printString(str);
                         MainActivity.printString(str);


                    }

                    if(req_tx != 0){
                        req_tx = 0;
                        out.write(txdata,0,txlen);
                        out.flush();
                    }
                    if (len > 0) {
                        //listener.onReceive(rxbuf,len);
                        LteSms.RecvData(rxbuf,len);
                    }
                }
                //}
            } catch (IOException e) {
                str = "接続エラー" + e.toString();
                MainActivity.printString(str);
                startServer(serverip,serverportnum);
            }
        }
    }
```

error result:

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: listen failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketListen(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.listen(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:439)
W/System.err:     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:378)
W/System.err:     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
W/System.err:     at com.example.httpserver7.httprxtx.<init>(httprxtx.java:79)
W/System.err:     at com.example.httpserver7.httprxtx.startServer(httprxtx.java:382)
W/System.err:     at com.example.httpserver7.httprxtx$EchoThread.run(httprxtx.java:356)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: listen failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.listen(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.listen(ForwardingOs.java:150)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.listen(ForwardingOs.java:150)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketListen(PlainSocketImpl.java:180)
W/System.err:   ... 6 more
```